# Why Earth Engine output is incomplete when I run several scripts at once

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have several scripts that are identical. Except they are for different time windows. More precisely, I would like to run my code for different years, 2015, 2016, 2017 and 2018 separately. I have copied my script 4 times and run all at once on Google Earth Engine.

The output of some of them does not include the Sentinel bands such as B2, B3. It just includes my own original shapefile data.

Does EE have any limitation on how many scripts one can run at once? Do I have to pay Google to be able to run several scripts?

Here is my sample code:

```
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////
/////     We can read a shapefile with many polygons, and using map()
/////     read all images corresponding to a polygon. However, the result of
/////     that is a featureCollection for which we do not know how to
/////     access to the info. inside. So, we want to do a for-loop for each polygon 
/////     now.
/////

//##
//##    GLOBAL Variables
//##
var batch_A_2015_regions = ee.FeatureCollection(batch_A_2015_SF);
print ("Number of fields in the shapefile is", batch_A_2015_regions.size());

var start_date = '2015-01-01';
var end_date = '2015-12-31';
var cloud_perc = 70;
// print(batch_A_2015_regions);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///                           functions definitions start
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///  Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band.
///
function maskS2clouds(image) {
    var qa = image.select('QA60');

    // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
    var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

    // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
                        qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

    // Return the masked and scaled data, without the QA bands.
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
                          .select("B.*")
                          .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// add Day of Year to an image
///

function addDate_to_image(image){
  var doy = image.date().getRelative('day', 'year');
  var doyBand = ee.Image.constant(doy).uint16().rename('doy');
  doyBand = doyBand.updateMask(image.select('B8').mask());

  return image.addBands(doyBand);
}

////////////////////////
///
/// add Day of Year to an imageCollection
///

function addDate_to_collection(collec){
  var C = collec.map(addDate_to_image);
  return C;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// add NDVI to an image

function addNDVI_to_image(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// add NDVI to an imageCollection

function add_NDVI_collection(image_IC){
  var NDVI_IC = image_IC.map(addNDVI_to_image);
  return NDVI_IC;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// add EVI to an image

function addEVI_to_image(image) {
  var evi = image.expression(
                      '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1.0))', {
                      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
                      'RED': image.select('B4'),
                      'BLUE': image.select('B2')
                  }).rename('EVI');
  return image.addBands(evi);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// add EVI to an imageCollection

function add_EVI_collection(image_IC){
  var EVI_IC = image_IC.map(addEVI_to_image);
  return EVI_IC;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// Extract ImageCollection from Sentinel 2- level 1C 
/// dates etc are hard-coded to enable us to use map() function

function extract_sentinel_IC(a_feature){
    var geom = a_feature.geometry();
    var newDict = {'original_polygon_1': geom};
    var imageC = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
                .filterBounds(geom)
                //.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', "less_than", cloud_perc)
                .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloud_perc))
                //.filter('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE < 70')
                .sort('system:time_start', true);

    // toss out cloudy pixels
    imageC = imageC.map(maskS2clouds);

    // pick up some bands
    // imageC = imageC.select(['B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

    // add DoY as a band
    imageC = addDate_to_collection(imageC);

    // add NDVI as a band
    imageC = add_NDVI_collection(imageC);

    // add EVI as a band
    imageC = add_EVI_collection(imageC);

    // add original geometry to each image
    // we do not need to do this really:
    imageC = imageC.map(function(im){return(im.set(newDict))});

    // add original geometry and WSDA data as a feature to the collection
    imageC = imageC.set({ 'original_polygon': geom,
                          'WSDA':a_feature
                        });
    // imageC = imageC.sort('system:time_start', true);

    //imageC = imageC.map(add_NDVI_collection)
  return imageC;
}

function mosaic_and_reduce_IC_mean(an_IC){
  an_IC = ee.ImageCollection(an_IC);

  var reduction_geometry = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry(an_IC.get('original_polygon')));
  var WSDA = an_IC.get('WSDA');
  var start_date_DateType = ee.Date(start_date);
  var end_date_DateType = ee.Date(end_date);
  //######**************************************
  // Difference in days between start and end_date

  var diff = end_date_DateType.difference(start_date_DateType, 'day');

  // Make a list of all dates
  var range = ee.List.sequence(0, diff.subtract(1)).map(function(day){
                                    return start_date_DateType.advance(day,'day')});

  // Funtion for iteraton over the range of dates
  function day_mosaics(date, newlist) {
    // Cast
    date = ee.Date(date);
    newlist = ee.List(newlist);

    // Filter an_IC between date and the next day
    var filtered = an_IC.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));

    // Make the mosaic
    var image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic());

    // Add the mosaic to a list only if the an_IC has images
    return ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), newlist.add(image), newlist));
  }

  // Iterate over the range to make a new list, and then cast the list to an imagecollection
  var newcol = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(range.iterate(day_mosaics, ee.List([]))));
  //print("newcol 1", newcol);
  //######**************************************

  var reduced = newcol.map(function(image){
                            return image.reduceRegions({
                                                        collection:reduction_geometry,
                                                        reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                                                        scale: 10
                                                      });
                                          }
                        ).flatten();

  reduced = reduced.set({ 'original_polygon': reduction_geometry,
                        'WSDA':WSDA
                      });
  WSDA = ee.Feature(WSDA);
  WSDA = WSDA.toDictionary();

  // var newDict = {'WSDA':WSDA};
  reduced = reduced.map(function(im){return(im.set(WSDA))}); 
  return(reduced);
}

///
///                         functions definitions end
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var batch_A_2015_IC = batch_A_2015_regions.map(extract_sentinel_IC);
var all_fields_TS = batch_A_2015_IC.map(mosaic_and_reduce_IC_mean);
all_fields_TS = all_fields_TS.flatten();

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: all_fields_TS,
  description:'batch_A_2015_TS',
  folder:"00_TS_Batches_" + cloud_perc + "_cloud",
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});


// var batch_A_2015_IC_first = ee.ImageCollection(batch_A_2015_IC.first());
// print("1", batch_A_2015_IC.first());

// var an_imggg = batch_A_2015_IC_first.first();
// print("2", an_imggg);

// var batch_A_2015_IC_first_reduced = mosaic_and_reduce_IC_mean(batch_A_2015_IC_first);
// print ("3", batch_A_2015_IC_first_reduced);




// Export.table.toDrive({
//   collection:all_fields_TS.flatten(),
//   description:'batch_A_2015_TS',
//   folder:"batch_A_2015",
//   fileFormat: 'SHP'
// });



//#############################################################
//
//           Plot Charts on the right panel (Console)
//
//#############################################################

// var first_region = batch_A_2015_regions.first();
// var first_NDVI_TS = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear({
//                             imageCollection: batch_A_2015_IC_first, 
//                             bandName: 'NDVI', 
//                             region: first_region.geometry(), 
//                             regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean() 
//                             // scale: plot_scale
//                               });

// print(first_NDVI_TS);

//#############################################################
//
//                        Plot the Map below
//
//#############################################################

// Map.setCenter(-119.525, 47.525995, 16);
// // Map.addLayer(first_region.geometry())
// Map.addLayer(first_region.geometry(), 
//             {color: 'FF0000'}, 
//             'The farm is plotted in red');
```

I do not copy the same code in the same script. I have made several copy of the same script. I use different shapefile in each script.

To be more precise about the problem. The output have a given script is OK sometimes, but the same script may produce a bad output the next day.
It is random. I do not know what is going on!

My shapefiles have 15000 polygons in them. The code works just fine for the shapefiles with too few polygons.

Comment: Multiple scripts running at once should not interfere or give incorrect answers — at worst you will get "too many requests" type errors. Please edit your question to include an example script that exhibits the problem, so we can give more specific advice to solve your problem.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the same code block all in the same script? If so, some variables might not be reset properly between your two blocks, causing the errors.

Comment: @JonasV. I do not do what you said. Lets say I have script `A.js` and 10 shapefiles. I copied `A.js` 10 times and in each `A_i.js` I use a different shapefile.